# How to create request URL using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to create `GET` request to this API: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=myLatitude,myLongitude&sensor=true`

Instead of `myLatitude` and `myLongitude`, I need to put my own values. Below you can see how I tried to do request using Retrofit:

ApiInterface:

```
@GET("json?latlng={lat},{long}&sensor=true")
Call<JsonArray> getApproximateLocations(@Query(value = "lat" , encoded = true) String lat, @Query(value = "long" , encoded = true) String lon);
```

My request:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getString(R.string.location_base_api)).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class) ;

    mapsApiInterface.getApproximateLocations(String.valueOf(lat),String.valueOf(lon)).enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
```

My base URL is: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/`.

The result of this code is following error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "latlng={lat},{long}&sensor=true" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.`

So, why I get this error and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@GET("json?latlng={lat},{long}&sensor=true")
Call<JsonArray> getApproximateLocations(@Query(value = "lat" , encoded = true) String lat, @Query(value = "long" , encoded = true) String lon);
```

should be like:

```
@GET("json")
Call<JsonArray> getApproximateLocations(
    @Query(value = "latlng" , encoded = true) String latLng/* pass formatted string here (e.g. 2.1367,2.3199 */, 
    @Query(value = "sensor") boolean isSensor);
```

Comment: Thanks, worked. But your answer leads to this question: How Do I need to do if I have long line after latlng? I don't think that I need to write inside @GET each of them. In this case I need to put values to their places. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Query parameters are really simple, they are each segment of Url after '?' and they are splitted by '&'. Retrofit gives you ability to set path, query params, url and other things. In your method you should specify dynamic part of your URL. in your case you can put @GET("json?sensor=true") and remove "@Query(value = "sensor") boolean isSensor" part from method signature. Query params order doesn't matter. Just separate static part from dynamic

Answer (score 1):

> Do like this:

```
@GET( Constants.GET_ADDRESS_BY_LOCATION )
    ServiceCall<Response> getAddress(@Query(Constants.PATH_LATLNG) String latlng, @Query(Constants.PATH_LANGUAGE) String language , @Query(Constants.KEY_GOOGLE_MAP_API) String key);
```

**GET_ADDRESS_BY_LOCATION** is API
while other constants are parameters required